# generate the subset based on a given index set

Tags: r

There has a data set, A, like

```
id grade
1  10
2  20
3  30
4  40
```

In addition, there has another index data set, B, like

```
id
2
3
```

I would like to extract the subset of A based on B, the result will look like

```
id  grade
2   20
3   30
```

Comment: `merge(A, B)`? `A[A$id %in% B$id, ]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` solution. This will be much faster if your dataset `A` is large, or if you have to do this a large number of times.

```
set.seed(1)                                  # for reproducible example
A <- data.frame(id=1:1e6,grade=10*(1:1e6))   # 1,000,000 rows
B <- data.frame(id=sample(1:1e6,1000))       # random sample of 1000 ids

library(data.table)
setDT(A)              # convert A to a data.table
setkey(A,id)          # set the key
result <- A[J(B$id)]  # extract records based in id
```

In this example `data.table` is about 20 times faster than either `%in%` or `merge(...)`.

Note also that while all three retrieve the same records, they are not necessarily in the same order.

```
A$id %in% B$id
```

creates a logical vector the length of `A$id`, which elements are `T` if that element is found in `B$id`, then uses that to subset `A`. So the records in the result are in the same order as `A`.

```
merge(A,B)
```

sorts the result by the common column (`id`), so the result is sorted by increasing value of `id`. In your example and this example, these first two are the same.

```
A[J(B$id)]
```

returns a result ordered as `B$id` (which is random, in this example, but would be the same as the other two approached in your example).

Comment: (+1), nice `data.table` solution, but I think it will be better to convert `B` to `data.table` too and then merge the, e.g., `setkey(setDT(A), id); setkey(setDT(B), id); A[B]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I profiled them both and `A[J(B$id)]` was ~50% faster.

Comment: I don't think (after validating) there is a difference, only if you consider (2 microseconds is twice worse than 1 microsecond), but you have a point here, as `B$id` is actually a vector rather a `data.frame` (thanks to @Arun for pointing this out), so it should have more or less same efficiency in this specific case

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
> x <- data.frame(id=1:4, grade=(1:4)*10)
> x
  id grade
1  1    10
2  2    20
3  3    30
4  4    40
> id <- 2:3
> x[ x$id %in% id, ]
  id grade
2  2    20
3  3    30
```

Alternatively you can also:

```
> id <- data.frame(id=2:3)
> merge(x, id)
  id grade
1  2    20
2  3    30
```